# SQL query different results between workbench and PHP script in the same date range

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that helps me to make some financial reports like capital, profits, total sold item, total item in store between 2 dates:

```
$result[] = 0;
$res[] = 0;
$fetchStat[]=0;
if(isset($_POST['generate_capital']))
{
 $from_d = $_POST['from_d'];
 $to_d = $_POST['to_d'];
 $stat = "SELECT sum(sell_quantity*(sell_price-init_price)) AS 'rebeh', sum(init_price*(quantity-sell_quantity)) AS 'capital', sum(sell_price*sell_quantity) AS 'profits', sum(quantity) AS 'total_item', sum(sell_quantity) AS 'total_sell' FROM purchases WHERE date_now BETWEEN :d1 AND :d2";
 $stmtStat = $conn->prepare($stat);
 $stmtStat->bindValue(':d1', $from_d);
 $stmtStat->bindValue(':d2', $to_d);
 $execStat = $stmtStat->execute();
 $fetchStat= $stmtStat->fetchAll();
}
```

Now, the same query in MySQL workbench will give me a specific result:

```
SELECT sum(sell_quantity*(sell_price-init_price)) AS 'rebeh', 
sum(init_price*(quantity-sell_quantity)) AS 'capital', sum(sell_price*sell_quantity) AS 'profits', 
sum(quantity) AS 'total_item', 
sum(sell_quantity) AS 'total_sell' 
FROM purchases WHERE date_now BETWEEN '2016-02-02' AND '2016-05-09'
```

The result is:

[image]

And the same query in the PHP script with the same date range will give me other values:

[image]

I've changed the Arabic keywords with English ones so you can see the difference.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT: Adding var_dump result for 2 dates**
[image]

Comment: The date ranges came through the form correctly? If you statically set the `where` to `BETWEEN '2016-02-02' AND '2016-05-09'` in the PHP does it work?

Comment: Can you print the `$from_d` and `$to_d` to check they are giving the exact date with the right format

Comment: Yes. The results are the same. Okay let me edit my answer @AmanRawat

Comment: See the end of my question please

Comment: have you tried  @chris85 answer

Comment: Yeah I am working on it

Comment: Guys, when I enter manually the date inside date input instead of selecting them using arrows, it works properly and the results are the same.

Comment: When I use the date input selectors to select the date I see a big difference. But when I type them into the date input using my keyboard I get the correct values in both workbench and my web app page

Comment: `Var_dump` both inputs, are they the same?

Comment: Yeah Both `var_dump` results are the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, it appears that the most likely cause is that your date formats have the month and day in the wrong order, for the 2nd of February, that doesn't matter, but for the 9th of May, it would become the 5th of September.

Now, the reason that the data for the 9th of May isn't included when you run the query directly is because a date is actually midnight on that date, making it exclusive of that date when it comes at the end of a between.

It's possible there is something else, so if this doesn't work, try echoing out all your values at every point, until you know exactly what is being run, and it should become clear.

To clarify, when using '/' in a date, MySQL uses the following format:

`'%d/%m/%Y'`

Which would explain why it works if you enter a string into your text box.

Comment: Okay, the problem start when `to_d` is form first of May and Above

Comment: Sir. When I use the date input selectors to select the date I see a big difference. But when I type them into the date input using my keyboard I get the correct values in both workbench and my web app page

Comment: Hopefully that update helps, you can either process the date using PHP, or update your date picker to format it 'day/month/year'.